# Have the same rendered output, whether the video is a local or remote ressource

Tags: files, media, nodes

I need to let contributor either upload video or link to some remote streams (youtube).

For this, I use [media](http://drupal.org/project/media) (and media_youtube) module.

I works well for remote ressources, however when I try to upload a video instead, the video appears as a link, on the front (though I tried to fumble with the manage display settings for this peculiar field).

I tried to implement [jwplayer](http://drupal.org/project/jw_player) for the local videos, but it did not work this time. I also had a look at [mediafront](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront) module, but as far as I know, it does not handle "local" videos (I may be wrong, but it seems overkill).

Have you been facing such a problem before, that is render a consistent display (a player with the same dimensions), regardless of the source (local or remote) ? 
Can you point me to some resources ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it yet, but I believe that is what is good about the mediafront module.  It wraps the youtube or local videos in it's own themeable player.

You could also try http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement module, though I'm not sure how well that display's youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

i had tried many options to deal with video, i believe that video hosting and publishing solution for delivering professional quality video to digital audiences on any device.
you can try [Brightcove Video Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/brightcove). it also has an integration with [media module](https://www.drupal.org/project/brightcove_media).